# Vuetify 2.3.4 date picker close-on-content click seems to be "malfunctioning"

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I am very new to Vuetify and Vue.js.  I am not sure how or why something is not working properly with my 2 date pickers closing when I select a date.  Also, I grabbed this code from the online documentation/api at : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/

It's with the calendar closing after I select a value.

According to the documentation, *close-on-content-click* should be set to "true" if you want the calendar to close after user selects a value.

The online sample has close-on-content-click="false", yet the calendar closes after selection?  Why and how?

On the page I'm developing, I have two date pickers. Both of them are set close-on-content-click="false".  One of them closes after selection, one does not.

Why is the online sample closing when it shouldn't?  And why is half of my code behaving improperly?  I am confused.  Am I missing something?

Relevant code below.

```html
<v-row>
    <v-col md6>
        <v-menu
                v-model="WhenStartedDate"
                :close-on-content-click="false"
                :nudge-right="40"
                transition="scale-transition"
                offset-y
                min-width="290px"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-text-field
                        v-model="newEvent.whenStartedDate"
                        label="Event Start Date"
                        prepend-icon="event"
                        readonly
                        v-bind="attrs"
                        v-on="on"
                ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker v-model="newEvent.whenStartedDate" @input="WhenStarteDate = false"></v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
    </v-col>
    <v-col md6>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
<v-row>
    <v-col md6>
        <v-menu
                v-model="WhenEndedDate"
                :close-on-content-click="false"
                :nudge-right="40"
                transition="scale-transition"
                offset-y
                min-width="290px"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-text-field
                        v-model="newEvent.whenEndedDate"
                        label="Event End Date"
                        prepend-icon="event"
                        readonly
                        v-bind="attrs"
                        v-on="on"
                ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker v-model="newEvent.whenEndedDate" @input="WhenEndedDate = false"></v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
    </v-col>
    <v-col md6>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still working on this? Let me know, otherwise please accept my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your menus is behaving properly because you have a typo in one of the variables referenced in it. The other is not behaving properly because it has the correct variable name, and it's doing exactly what you tell it, which is to close the menu.

The value you pass to `v-model` acts as the open/closed state, and will potentially *override* `close-on-content-click`. You have two `v-model`s attached to each menu: one called `WhenStartedDate` and one `WhenEndedDate`. You are setting them to `false` in each of the `@input` events in the two datepicker components, and doing this will forcibly close the two menus... but not quite, as there is a typo in one of them: `@input="WhenStarteDate = false"` is missing a "d". That's why that one is *not* closing, but the other is.

To keep both menus open after selecting a date, simply remove the two `@input="..."` handlers from the two `v-date-picker`s.

Example in codepen: https://codepen.io/mlillie87/pen/ZEQRamL?editors=1010

Comment: First off, so sorry about the typo.  I checked and double checked, especially as I know I'm bad for that.  There must be a meme for that somewhere.

Comment: Your answer had lots of good information, but I confess I don't really understand it all because I really don't know what I'm doing tbh.  I just copied from the documentation.  Am i doing the v-model wrong?  And I dont' really know what that @input tag is for...would you know a good overview of the basics of this stuff by any chance?

Comment: I would recommend reading the Vue.js documentation, and rewriting all of your code not to use the shortcuts while you are learning. For example, `@input` is the same as `v-on:input`.

Comment: Have followed your suggestion re: not using shortcuts. Have been perusing Vue Vuetify documentation...that's fun.  Question, if I may.  Why would the example code on the Vuetify site bother with the whole @input="blah = false" and also have close-on-content-click = false?  Why have both when one overrides the other?  Something I'm not getting here...